# Understanding JavaScript Closures with a small example

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to get around understanding javascript closures from a practical scenario.I know from a theoretical perspective , With the help of closures inner functions can have access to the variables in the enclosing function i.e parent function.

I have read a couple of questions on stackOverflow as well.

i am really missing the point of what is happening here?

```
var foo = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  foo[i] = function(){
  return i;
}  
}
console.log(foo[0]());
```

This gives me out a 10. Most of the articles say that by the time it reaches the inner anonymous function, The for loop is getting executed as a result the last value that is present in the loop which is 10 is being printed.

But i am still not able to get to the bottom of this.

On Contrary, If i use something like:

```
var foo = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
 (function(){
   var y =i;
   foo[i] = function(){
   return y;
 }
 })();
 }
console.log(foo[0]());
```

I am getting the output.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this code block helps

```js
var foo = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    foo[i] = function() {
        return i; // is a reference and will always be the value, which 'i' have on function execution
    }
}
// 'i' is 10 here!
console.log(foo[0]()); // executing the function will return the current value of 'i'

///////////////////////////////////////

var foo = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    /* thats a IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) */
    (function(a) { // 'a' is now a local variable
        foo[a] = function() { // defines a function
            return a; // is a reference to local variable 'a'
        };
    })(i); // <- passing the current value of i as parameter to the invoked function
}
// 'i' is 10 here
console.log(foo[0]()); // returns the reference to 'a' within the same scope, where the function was defined
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first scenario, all of your functions added to the `foo` array are referencing the same `var i`. All functions will return whatever `i` was set to last, which is `10` because during the last iteration of the loop that's what it's value was set to.

In the second scenario, you are Immediately Invoking this function:

```
(function(){
  var y =i;
  foo[i] = function(){
    return y;
  }
})();
```

By immediately invoking it you are effectively locking in the local state of `var y`, for each iteration of the loop - it provides a unique scope for each function added to the array.

Comment: @hackkerdave I did not use the var y in my first example right?